# How to prevent object from rotating 360deg when reaching full circle?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a image which always points in the direction of the mouse.
At some point the angle goes from `180deg` to `-180deg`, how do I get the image to take the short angle instead of doing full circle?

```
// Find ship angle (Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / Math.PI;).
var mouseAngle = getAngle(FIREFLY.CENTER.X, FIREFLY.CENTER.Y, currentMousePos[0], currentMousePos[1]);

var turnDegrees = mouseAngle - FIREFLY.ANGLE;
var maxDegrees = 5;

console.log(mouseAngle + " " + FIREFLY.ANGLE);

if (turnDegrees > -5 && turnDegrees < 5) {
    // Do nothing.
} else if (turnDegrees < 0) {
    FIREFLY.ANGLE -= 5;
} else {
    FIREFLY.ANGLE += 5;
}

// Set ship direction.
FIREFLY.style.transform = 'rotate(' + (FIREFLY.ANGLE + 90) + 'deg)';
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/ro9y95b5/2/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angles are the same modulo 360 degrees, so to avoid big rotations like 359° you choose -1° and to avoid -359° you choose 1°

You could do something like

```
var turnDegrees = (mouseAngle - FIREFLY.ANGLE) ;
if(-540<turnDegrees&&turnDegrees <=-180) turnDegrees+=360;
else if(180<turnDegrees&&turnDegrees<=540) turnDegrees-=360;
```

but it turns out FIREFLY.ANGLE can take large values, so to avoid plenty of other if clauses, a general formula is better. Here is one using modulo

```
var turnDegrees =  mod(mouseAngle - FIREFLY.ANGLE +180, 360) -180;
function mod(x, value){ // Euclidean modulo
    return x>=0 ? x%value : value+ x%value;
}
```

[plot test](http://jsfiddle.net/cLvmrs6m/4/)

fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/crl/2rz296tf/31

Comment: This is better indeed, though it still takes the long angle some times. Could you explain the math to me?

Answer (score 0):

You could turn off CSS transforms, and do the interpolation yourself.

Try calculating the difference between the angles when the mouse moves and add that to a total angle, that way the angle wont be bound to (-180, 180)